# Add Social Icons to Shopify Header.Liquid

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I'm using the Shopify [Parallax Theme from OOTSB](https://outofthesandbox.com/collections/parallax-theme). I want to add the same social icons that are in `footer.liquid` to `header.liquid`. I see that `{% include 'social-icons' %}` is a snippet used by `footer.liquid` to call these icons:
[image]

The social icons look great in the footer:
[image]

How do I add this snippet to `header.liquid` so the icons show up between the logo and the menu?
[image]

I found a (logical?) place to put the snippet in the `header.liquid` file, but as you can see, 1.) the icons show up vertically, 2.) the icons are not to the right of the logo as desired. 3.) I have no idea how to control the placement/size/padding/etc. of these icons.
[image]

Comment: this is due to css style conflict with header and footer styles ? if you can host this page and share preview url, so can check the HTML structure and CSS properties for header & footer individually.

Comment: Hi @Selvam, thank you for your response. I am unfamiliar with how to host a Shopify page as a standalone site. Is there anything I could post here to get you the required info?

Comment: you can go to https://jsfiddle.net paste your header section code in HTML section and share me the link url here.